# How do I make a button resize the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on a trigonometry calculator and I wanted to make this button resize the window based on the resolution of the frame:

```
res_btn = Button(frame2,
                   text='⮞',
                   command= resolution)
res_btn.pack(side= LEFT, padx=2)
```

This calls the function:

```
def resolution():
    frame.update()
    print(f"{frame.winfo_reqwidth()} x {frame.winfo_reqheight()}")
    
    customRes = f"{frame.winfo_reqwidth() + 15}x{frame.winfo_reqheight() + 15}"
```

However, when I set the original window geometry function to the variable `customRes` it does not change:

```
global customRes
customRes = '500x500'

root = Tk()
root.title('Sin Rule Calculator - Manpreet Singh')
root.geometry(customRes)
root.configure(bg='#686e70')
```

(Let me know if you need the whole source code)

Comment: Are you calling `root.geometry` in your `resolution()` function?  There isn't a "live" connection between the `customRes` global and the window size.  It's just a string.

Comment: @TimRoberts I assumed that if I reassigned the variable it would automatically change the res, but I made the "live" connection in the function.

It works now. Thanks!

Comment: And just as another subtle note -- the `customRes` in your `resolution` function is local to that function.  It's completely separate from the global, unless you add a `global` statement to that function.  But don't do that -- you don't need it.